# User permission check steps in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, permissions, authlogic

I want to understand the sequence of steps how it is verified that a user has permission to particular application page ('Acl', 'Auth', 'Security' components are used). For example, a visitor clicks a link on another site that directs him to my application. What is the sequence of steps that my application does to verify that this user has access to the page? What controllers/classes and methods are called?

Answer (score 0):

1. if Auth is required on that page,
   your app checks if a user is logged
   in
2. if not, it redirects to login page
3. if yes, your app should check
   permission,
4. normally, it checks your user group
   to see if that group has permission
   on that page
5. if it does, it checks that username
   to see if that user has permission
   on that page

logics for 3,4 and 5 should be done in app_controller

thats my take on it.

Comment: As far as I understand I provide merely settings for Auth component in app_controller. All logics is somewhere else. I would like to know where is that logics (what class) and the sequence of methods called.